# How do I fix the problem of cloning project from gitlab?

Tags: php, laravel, git, gitlab

I want to clone a project from gitlab with:
 git clone https://url
but I have error:
 Failed to connect to gitlab.com port 443: Timed out
(While my vpn is connected!)

Comment: You need to use vpn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a VPN to connect to gitlab. I think you are in Iran, Negar.

Comment: Yes it is true but my vpn is connected...

Comment: Not every VPN works for using in command line. If you work with Windows, try Hotspot Shield.

Answer (score 2):

Enable local network in your Vpn client settings and make sure you can telnet to the 443 port on the URL. double check if you want to connect to github or gitlab.